# ExtJS 6 store.remove(records) -> store.sync() don't trigger the server

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I use ExtJS 6.0.0, REST proxy with TreeStore. So when i remove some records from the store *store.remove(records)*, then try to sync changes with server and call *store.sync()* and nothing happend! A callback function of sync not called.

url: '/admin/pages', return simple nested data in proper format.
View and update operations work well.

I made a simple code fragment just to illustrate the issue:

```
    Ext.define('Pages', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',     type: 'int'},
            {name: 'parent_id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'title', type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    Ext.onReady(function() {

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            model: 'Pages',
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: '/admin/pages',
            }
        });

        var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            rootVisible: false,
            store: store,
            multiSelect: true,
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                text: 'title',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'title'
            }],
            tbar: [
                {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    handler: function () {

                        var records = tree.getSelection();
                        store.remove(records); // remove nodes from tree
                        store.sync(); // do nothing!! WHY?

                    },
                }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: have you tried [autoSync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.ProxyStore-cfg-autoSync)?

Comment: Yes, same result. GET POST PUT request is ok, but no DELETE.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-removeChild) can help you

Answer (score 0):

If the store is configured as autoSync:true the record's endEdit method will have already internally caused a save to execute on the store. We only need to save manually when autoSync is false, otherwise, we'll create duplicate transactions.
You need to the call the store.load() after you do the syncing using store.sync()